# I have lots of images on a html page - how can i make certain ones load first (or certain ones load last)?

Tags: javascript, html

i have a page with the main content area being big thumbnails, but elsewhere on the page are about 100-200 other (smaller) thumbs that are not important but must still show.

What ways do i have to make the main ones show first (or the unimportant ones show last)?

I was thinking of these ways:

JS load: on page load (once it has finished loading), use a jquery's append() (or whatever other way) to write the html with the image code

Set all unimportant images inside a div with style="display:none;". Then once the page has loaded, use JS to set it as visible

what do you think is the best way?

Comment: What happens if you leave it to the browser to decide? I'd expect it to start with ones at the top which normally would be the most important ones.

Comment: @macleojw: File size is the biggest factor in leaving the browser to determine which ones show first.  Smaller images would download quicker and thus be displayed first.

Comment: @imlostmike why don't you use image sprites?

Comment: I do leave it to the browser, it loads ones at the top (which have to be at the top) first.

sprites won't work due to ever changing content

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out the [YUI ImageLoader](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/imageloader/). It basically loads images only if/when they are needed (i.e. scrolled into view).

Comment: @Felix That is not what he asked for

Comment: no idea why you have a down vote. this seems perfect.

it looks like it can be modified so scrolling is required.

thanks ( i would vote up but i think i have to validate my email or something to do that)

Comment: @c0mrade No, but maybe it's what he wants.

Answer (score 1):

I would set the 'src' of all images to be a transparent 1 pixel gif and then use JS to loop through the images, 'in order of importance', and set the 'src' attribute on page load.

Comment: i second pb. you can use an array list in the order you wish to load.